# With XPath, select parent instead, if all children are selected

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have a stylesheet (XSLT 2.0) that removes elements. Now I have an issue where the DTD of the XML I am "pruning" does not allow me to remove all elements under a certain node, without removing the empty node as well. Hence I want to remove the parent element as well if all the children are removed. I want to select the elements to remove with an XPath expression.

As an example, consider this XML (the DTD is not provided, but basically states that a box must contain at least one crayon):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <box>
        <crayon color="red"/>
        <crayon color="red"/>
        <crayon color="red"/>
        <crayon/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <crayon/>
        <crayon/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <crayon color="red"/>
        <crayon color="red"/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <crayon color="red"/>
        <crayon color="red"/>
        <crayon color="red"/>
        <crayon/>
    </box>
</test>
```

The output I want is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <box>
        <crayon/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <crayon/>
        <crayon/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <crayon/>
    </box>
</test>
```

This is a stylesheet that unfortunately does not do what I want, but shows the form I want to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Next row should apply to sets of crayons or complete boxes. -->
    <xsl:template match="//box[if (count(crayon[@color = 'red']) = count(crayon)) then (.) else (crayon[@color = 'red'])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The reason that I want to manage this using one XPath expression is that I have a function that generates the stylesheet, taking the XPath as the input argument.

Comment: So which of the `box`es in the your input sample needs to be removed? All for them seem to meet the requirement "states that a box must contain at least one crayon". I am afraid posting code that does not do what you want without explaining with input -> output samples and/or in plain text what you want to achieve is not going to make it easy on us to help.

Comment: So you want to remove all `<crayon color="red"/>` and you want to remove the parent `box` as well if it has nothing but `<crayon color="red"/>` children?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes! You have understood correctly. Sorry if this was not clear in the above.

Comment: Is it possible to apply 2 transformations after another? Are you limited to XSL transformations? Why not code something in a real programming language?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: As regards sequences of transformations, it is possible with my current script, but not a very nice solution. I use Saxon-HE to do the transformation and I am trying to use the XPath standard to provide a flexible and powerful solution. I do not want to have to create a new procedure every time a user wants to filter something new. I also do not want the user to have to write an add-on for any filter not supported by my script. I think it would be hard for me to beat XPath when it comes to flexibility and ability to support scenarios I have not considered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 or Altova 2017 or 2018 or Exselt) an option? There you could exploit the new `xsl:where-populated` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#element-where-populated):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="box">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="box/crayon[@color = 'red']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2g

I am not quite sure which part you need to set us a parameter or variable but XSLT 3 with shallow attributes eases that task as well.

Using XSLT 2 I think you can use

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">


  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="box[not(crayon[not(@color = 'red')])] | box/crayon[@color = 'red']"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nbUY4kp

Comment: Since I use the latest Saxon 9.8, the proposed XSLT would run, but as I wrote, I need this in one XPath expression. I don't want XML code as input to my function. Your proposal for XSLT 2.0 worked beautifully though! Although I don't quite understand how the XPath works. Will it always select according to the first "argument" to the or function if it is fulfilled, or does it select the union of the two sets?

Comment: Any XSLT match pattern of the form `match="foo | bar"` is simply a shorthand for having two separate templates `<xsl:template match="foo">...</xsl:template>` and `<xsl:template match="bar">...</xsl:template>` so having one empty `<xsl:template match="box[not(crayon[not(@color = 'red')])] | box/crayon[@color = 'red']"/>` is a shorthand for two empty `<xsl:template match="box[not(crayon[not(@color = 'red')])]"/>` and `<xsl:template match="box/crayon[@color = 'red']"/>`.